# How to get rid of "this script contains malicious content" error?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, vbscript

I've made a VB script for my startup procedure in Windows 10 that launches an executable. It uses the following structure:

```
Dim Host
Set Host = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Host.Run "MyExecutable.exe 'parameter'", 0
```

After a recent update a couple weeks ago, I started getting this window on startup:

```
Script:
Path\to\script.vbs
Line: 6
Char: 1
Error: This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software.: 'Run'
Code: 800A802D
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

As expected, there is an issue with running the necessary command via `Host.Run "MyExecutable.exe 'parameter'", 0`

I tried signing the script, but this didn't help, even though the signature is valid and the key is accepted by my system. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Add an exception to your antivirus

Comment: I have several such scripts on my machine, and MalwareBytes premium does not block them. Should I be worried?